# jQuery .html() vs .text() produce different result in .hover() function

Tags: jquery

I have a issue where in I am using the .hover() function. If I use .text() function to add the html (anchor tag) which I am dynamically creating, it works fine, both the functions are called as desired. But when I use the .html() function instead then the second function of .hover() is never been called.

```
var i = 0;      
textItems = new Array();    
////I am putting the value into textItems using the jquery ajax call  
////and i get its value from a .each() function.  

//.text() implementation  
$('#textArea-id').hover(  
        function() {  
            $('#textArea-id').text(textItems[i]);   
        },  
        function() {  
            //-->mouseout function is called here  
        }  
    );  

//.html() implementation  
$('#textArea-id').hover(  
        function() {  
            $('#textArea-id').html(textItems[i]);  
        },  
        function() {  
            //-->mouseout function is never been called  
        }  
    );
```

Comment: Can you post the value returned by the Ajax call?

Comment: Can you post all of the relevant code ? Debug, see what comes back from the ajax, and post that too!

Comment: Tried to reproduce this but couldn't. One thing to try is if it works if you set the html to a simple tag like <span>a</span>. Can you try to reproduce the problem at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I am getting xml and parsing it and storing it in textItems array, one of the value i get is <a href="www.xyx.com">Click here</a>

Comment: This test works fine: http://jsbin.com/oguda4/2/edit . It must have something to do with the content in the hovered element, or the new content, so you'll need to give more details or provide a non-working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved. I follow the approach where in anchor tag is added to the code when html is rendered from the server and then dynamically set the href parameter and the inside text using jquery.